# Find a volume of a figure given by an astroid rotating around an axis

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, area

In the class we were given a task to find a volume of a figure of revolution. The figure is an astroid $x=a\cos^3{t}, y=a\sin^3{t}$ axis is $x=a$. And I thought that instead of doing integration (wich we were meant to do) I had an idea of calculating it as following: 
**first** calculate area of the astroid (the only part with integration), **second** find volume as product of *area* and its *path*. In our case *path* is a length of the circle of area $a$. Is it correct idea?

Here is my calculation 
$$a\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^3tdt=a\frac{2}{3}$$ this is the fourth part of area so the full area is $a\frac{8}{3}$. And the volume is 
$$a\frac{8}{3}2\pi a=\frac{16}{3}\pi a^2$$

Is it correct? I mean not the calculation but do we have right to do it this way? (Without taking "volume integral" and moving axis).

Comment: Yes I understand that it should be proportional to $a^3$ but I cant see were the third *a* should pop up

Comment: Your idea is correct. It is called [Pappus's centroid theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem). You have made a mistake in the computation of the astroid's area, since it must be proportional to $a^2$. Note that you should prove that the centroid is at distance $a$ from the axis (but it is easy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but your calculus of the area is wrong.

The part of the area that you want is:
$$
A/4=\int _0^a y(x) dx
$$
note that here the integration is with respect to $x$ and not $t$. You can use  the parametric equations to find $dx= 3a\cos^2 t (-\sin t) dt$ and substute in the integral with care to the limits of integration, and you find for your area:

$$
A/4=3a^2 \int_{\pi/2}^0  \sin^3 t \cos^2 t(-\sin t)dt
$$
calculating this integral (see [here](http://home.scarlet.be/math/oppbere.pdf)) you find for the entire area $A=3 \pi a^2/8$.
So the volume is $V=2\pi a A=3\pi^2a^3/4$